# How to upload data on cloud with SIM900

Tags: https, cloud, microcontroller, gsm, iot

I want to make a college project in which I want to track location of anything and update the data on cloud and read it afterwards. I have the data of GPS module, but I am confused about how to upload the data on cloud. I have a little idea that I can do this with GSM module by sending one https request.
But I have a doubt that when I am doing the HTTPS GET request then I am getting the html code of the website. Which is not of my use. 
Is there any other module to do so. Or I am doing something wrong with GET request. Please help me with this.
Every help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you will send data from your IoT devices to an endpoint on cloud (IoT Hub). The IoT devices will use device SDK to communicate with cloud. Once the data is captured by IoT Hub, you can manage the instance using service SDKs. This data can further be transformed by other services like Stream Analytics, etc.

Resources:

Connecting to IoT Hub: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/iot/get-started/

SDKs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a program I made to send data to my Azure IoT Hub via HTTPS using SIMCOM Modules (SIM800, SIM900...): https://developer.mbed.org/users/BorjaTarazona/code/Azure_SIM800_HelloWorld/

To upload the data to your IoT Hub via HTTPS using a SIM900 module you need:

1. APN for the SIM900 module. The APN is given by your network provider.
2. A Connection URL that will look like this: "https://XXXXXXXX.azure-devices.net/devices/XXXXX/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03"
3. A Shared Access Signature that you can get from your Azure account. It should be something similar to this one: "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=XXXXX.azure-devices.net&sig=rCD5ZWvjblAl20djcEdtuL40vpKmdjvQH7lTphIRtJo%3D&se=XXXXXXXXX"

The commands I use to send data to Azure using HTTPS with the SIM900 moudle are:

Initialization

1. Set context type: AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"\r\n
2. Set APN: AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","YourAPN"\r\n
3. Open bearer: AT+SAPBR=1,1\r\n
4. Query bearer: AT+SAPBR=2,1\r\n
5. Enable HTTP functions: AT+HTTPINIT\r\n
6. Enable SSL: AT+HTTPSSL=1\r\n

Data transmission

7. Set bearer profile identifier: AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1\r\n
8. Set the URL: AT+HTTPPARA="URL","YourURL"\r\n
9. Set the shared access signature: AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Authorization: YourSharedAccessSignature"\r\n
10. Set Content-Type field in the HTTP header: AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"\r\n
11. Set the JSON string to be sent: AT+HTTPDATA=StringLength,20000\r\nYourJSONString
12. HTTP POST: AT+HTTPACTION=1\r\n